# git says it's up to date when it's not

Tags: git

I made some changes to a file. Did a git status, saw it changed. Did a git add of that file. Then I committed the file with git commit -m "message". But when I push the change it says "Everything is up to date". The changes I made were significant. How can I correct this?t this?

Comment: Did you `git commit`?

Comment: For your description you didn't [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) anything, consequently everything is up to date because there is no new commit to push.

Comment: sorry, yes. I did a git commit. I've edited the OP to reflect that.

Comment: what does git remote -v tell you? is origin set to the right remote repo?

Comment: For sanity sake- what does running `git status` again tell you?

Comment: git remote -v shows this `git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@codehub.us.companyworld.company.com:7999/~tdunphy/aws_scripts.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@codehub.us.companyworld.company.com:7999/~tdunphy/aws_scripts.git (push)` and git status shows this `On branch rotate_aws_keys_singleton
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/rotate_aws_keys_singleton'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean`. Even tho there are changes that were made to the file I added and committed.

Comment: if you run `git log origin/rotate_aws_keys_singleton`, do you see your new commit?

Answer (score 3):

Git will push a local branch to its upstream on remote. If you created a new local branch on your machine, by default there's no remote upstream branch for it.
Depending on which version of git you are using, git shows different messages.

### On git versions < 2.x

When you do a git push for a branch which does not have a remote upstream set, you will see a message-

```
Everything up-to-date
```

In this case, you need to set up a remote upstream while you do a push. For eg.

```
$>git push my-branch -u origin my-branch
```

This will create a new remote upstream for your local my-branch. Every other commit push after this will be just

```
$>git push
```

### On git versions > 2.x

When you do a git push for a branch which does not have a remote upstream set, you will see a message-

```
fatal: The current branch my-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin my-branch
```

As this message is quite self explanatory, you know what needs to be done. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: It writes however `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/rotate_aws_keys_singleton'` at status

Answer (score 1):

When you `git add` a file, the changes are just "staged". You must `git commit` to update those changes in your local repository before you `git push`; otherwise, the changes are not pushed to the remote repository.

Comment: sorry, yes. I did a git commit. I've edited the OP to reflect that.